# HashSet cannot be converted to String error with instanceof operator

Tags: java, hashset, instanceof

I have these nested hashsets, in which the inner contain `String` values.

> {{a,b},{b,c},{c,e}}

At one point in my code, I do not know whether I am dealing with the inner hashset or the outer one. I am trying to ascertain by using the following line of code:

```
System.out.println(loopIterator3.next() instanceof String);
 //(FYI :Iterator <HashSet> loopIterator3 = hsConc2.iterator();)
```

This line of code seems to generate an error:

> prog.java:61: error: incompatible types: HashSet cannot be converted to String
>                   System.out.println(loopIterator3.next() instanceof String);

When `loopIterator3` is indeed traversing an inner hashset, i would expect
it would be taking String values.  Why does the compiler think it is a hashset?
Moreover, why does the compiler think I am trying to convert?

Any thoughts/suggestions?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<HashSet<String>> hashSets = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(newSet("a", "b"), newSet("b", "c"), newSet("c", "e")));

        System.out.println(hashSets.iterator().next() instanceof String); //error
        System.out.println(hashSets.iterator().next().iterator().next() instanceof String);
    }

    private static HashSet<String> newSet(String... str) {
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: I am trying to add code, the editor seems to have too many stipulations that I am working through ...

Comment: Add it, highlight it, press ctrl + k, then make sure there is a new line before and after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because `HashSet` and `String` are not related. I see that you already know the type of object returned by `next()` method. I did not understand the purpose. Still if you need this check, try something like below-

```
Object obj = loopIterator3.next();
String.class.isInstance(obj);
```

Answer (score 5):

> If a cast of the *RelationalExpression* to the *ReferenceType* would be
> rejected as a compile-time error, then the instanceof relational
> expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a
> situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be
> true.

Source:- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf (Page 513)

For example `a instanceof B` (a is object of class A) , if A and B are not in same heirarchy i.e they are not subclass or superclass of either then this is compile time error because if they are not in same heirarchy then it is not possible that a is instanceof B. So compiler shows error at compile time.

In your case HashSet is not a subclass or superclass of String and vice versa, therefore it is showing compile time error

Comment: Very informative, I would love to upvote your answer, but my reputation seems to be at 13, 2 shy of what is required to give upvotes.  If anybody gives my question an upvote, I must be good enough to give upvotes

Comment: Hey I guess I have the right to upvote now.  Do not bother to upvote my question unless you want to